# C++ pointers from a set of arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

```
cout << "\nSelected numbers: ";
    for (int x = 0; x < sizeB; x++)
    {
    if (x == (sizeB - 1))
        cout << arrayA[arrayB[n]];
    else
        cout << arrayA[arrayB[n]] << ", ";
    }
```

Hi, I have 2 arrays of integers, arrayA and arrayB, arrayA have a set of 50 values,
I need to use the values in arrayB to act as a pointers to point to the arrayA to return the values of the selected position.

For example, in this case:

```
arrayA= { 31,62,12,42,66 }
arrayB= { 1 , 4 }
```

the output should be 62 and 66.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Insert the index of the wanted values into the array B?

Comment: I am guessing you mean `x` instead of `n`.

Comment: What is your problem with the code? Do you get compiler or linker errors? Does it crash run-time? Please *edit your question* to elaborate.

Comment: Also, do you check that `arrayB[x]` is actually an element that exists in `arrayA` otherwise you are going to experience some **UB**.

Comment: A small (and unrelated to your problem) tip about your coding style: Try to avoid code duplication as much as possible. In your case with the code shown in your question the printing of the value from `arrayA` is done in both branches of the `if` statement. That means you can do it unconditionally in the loop, and only print the comma if it's not the last item being printed.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=0;i<arrayB.size();i++){
    cout << arrayA[arrayB[i]];
}
```

So basically it loops through the values in B, and uses the values there as indexes for arrayA. Fairly simple - let me know if you have any questions!
Cheers